# How to get rows of last minute of every month?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table that one of its column, named 'date', is of type `DATETIME`. I need to select all the rows that their date is the last minute of a month, for example:

```
31-12-17 23:59:00
30-11-17 23:59:00
```

How can I achieve this in one query?

Comment: My guess is that you're doing this to allow things like `a_column BETWEEN '01-12-17 00:00:00' AND '31-12-17 23:59:00'`?  If that's the case, then ***don't*** do this.  ***Everything*** become simplified if you do `a_column >= '01-12-17 00:00:00' AND a_column < '01-01-18 00:00:00'`

Comment: If less code is your thing, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28014b/7

Comment: @Strawberry - Would that not prevent any potential use of indexes?  And so be a bad idea?

Comment: @MatBailie If the OP wants rows corresponding to the last minute of each month, then I don't see that they've got much choice (except to include every possible permstation - there are only 12 , after all)

Comment: @MatBailie actually your guess is wrong: I only need to fetch rows that their date is the last minute of a month. If it causes index problems than perhaps I need to find another solution. Do you know any?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use **[`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day)** to get the last day of the month and **[`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** to get the time to compare.

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(<date_time_col>),"%d")=DATE_FORMAT(<date_time_col>,"%d") 
AND DATE_FORMAT(<date_time_col>,"%H:%i")='23:59';
```

---

**Detailed Explanation :**

So, basically, to get the correct row we need to get the *last day of the month* **AND** *last minute of the day*

`LAST_DAY` will help use to get the last day of the month for the given date-time. And `DATE_FORMAT` will help to get the date. Now, we will combine them together, to get the **last date** of the given date-time.

```
DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(<date_time_col>),"%d")
```

Above will return `29`, if last day of the month is `29-02-2018`.

Now, we need to check, if given date-time has last minute of the day ? We can again make use of `DATE_FORMAT` to extract time from the given date-time. Here, we will only concentrate on hour and minute (as per OP question). So, it should be

```
DATE_FORMAT(<date_time_col>,"%H:%i")
```

Above will return `23:59`, if given date-time is `29-02-2018 23:59:00`.

Comment: Putting the searched column inside those functions will prevent any use of indexes.  That's a generically bad idea.

Comment: @MatBailie I understand, there is always multiple way of solving each problem. But, as per OP question, I don't think any solution where we can solve this problem without using any function.

Comment: @Ravi, you might not be able to find that didn't use a function, but still, I think you could find one that used an index.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) to get the last day of each month:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(mydate)
```

returns:

```
2031-12-31
2030-11-30
```

Then use the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in order to get the last minute of the last day of each month:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LAST_DAY(mydate), 
                   ' ', 
                   '23:59:00'),
                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS last_min
```

returns:

```
last_min
--------------------
2031-12-31T23:59:00Z
2030-11-30T23:59:00Z
2030-11-30T23:59:00Z
```

You can now use `last_min` to compare with your actual datetime value.

If you want to get records whose datetime falls within the last minute *interval*, then you can additionally use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to get the *next minute* of the above datetime values:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(last_min, 
                INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) AS next_min
```

returns:

```
next_min
---------------------
2032-01-01T00:00:00Z
2030-12-01T00:00:00Z
2030-12-01T00:00:00Z
```

Using the above expressions you can build a predicate that checks for dates within the desired interval.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b45ba/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date) = LAST_DAY(date) AND HOUR(date) = 23 AND MINUTE(date) = 59;
```

Since this query won't use any index, it might be slow in a large table.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient solution could be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate IN
(
'2017-01-31 23:59:00',
'2017-03-31 23:59:00',
'2017-04-30 23:59:00',
'2017-05-31 23:59:00',
'2017-06-30 23:59:00',
'2017-07-31 23:59:00',
'2017-08-31 23:59:00',
'2017-09-30 23:59:00',
'2017-10-31 23:59:00',
'2017-11-30 23:59:00',
'2017-12-31 23:59:00'
)
OR mydate = '2017-03-01 00:00:00'- INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;
```